# Strange behavior of `new Date(Date.UTC)`

Tags: javascript, datetime

Strange behavior of `new Date(Date.UTC(...))` while converting date from **utc** to user's **local time**

I have timestamp getting from server which is like `2019-02-01 14:28:16` and I am trying to convert this timestamp to users local time in safe way to avoid *Invalid Date* error.

But surprisingly it converts **1st Feb** to **5th Feb**. Here is scenario:

```
const myDate = new Date('2019-02-01 14:28:16');

console.log('Step 1: MyDate: ' + myDate.toString());

const utcFormateOfMyDate = Date.UTC(
  myDate.getFullYear(),
  myDate.getMonth(),
  myDate.getDay(),
  myDate.getHours(),
  myDate.getMinutes(),
  myDate.getSeconds(),
  myDate.getMilliseconds()
);

console.log('Step 2: utcFormateOfMyDate: ' + utcFormateOfMyDate.toString()); // 1549376896000

console.log('Step 3.1 => ' + new Date(utcFormateOfMyDate)); // Tue Feb 05 2019 19:28:16 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time 

console.log('Step 3.2 => ' + Date(utcFormateOfMyDate)); // Fri Feb 01 2019 19:43:36 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
```

Only change which I did just added **new** keyword and converted timestamp jumped from **1st Feb** to **5th Feb** (in future); refer to screenshot

[image]

Although removing new keyword resolve the problem, But I could not found explanation of this magic effect. Can someone help me to understand this behavior?

Comment: There's no need to "convert" a date. Internally it's always UTC.

Comment: I am getting date in multiple formats; even Invalid Dates so for safety measure I did conversion to bye-pass bad formats. But I discover this magical behavior with `new` and without ~new~ keyword

Comment: The problem is that you're calling `getDay()` instead of `getDate()`.

Comment: For `Date.UTC(utcFormatOfMyDate)` it looks as if the function is just ignoring the out-of-range year value completely.

Comment: amazing you'r right

Comment: `getDay()` is for "day of the week" — I make that mistake a lot :)

Comment: @Pointy I think we all do. I can't remember a time I've had to take the day out of a Date object and not been confused by that method...

Comment: You shouldn't be doing `new Date('2019-02-01 14:28:16');` in the first place - it's unclear whether this is local time or UTC, and different browsers (versions) do behave differently. Instead, use the explicit `new Date('2019-02-01T14:28:16Z');` and don't worry about any "conversions".

Comment: @Bergi nice point but timestamp is not in my control; I get different formats such as (system mills, string,  '2019-02-01T14:28:16Z', even invalid dates :)) the problem was `getDay()` instead of `getDate()` in UTC conversion

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, the issue you are having is that you are comparing apples and oranges by accidentally passing the `Date.getDay` value (instead of `Date.getDate`) to `Date.UTC` and comparing the result with the output from parsing the timestamp directly. That said, you should not rely on `new Date()` or `Date()` to parse the timestamp as browser implementations vary and you may get inconsistent results.

Instead, you could do something like the following with the timestamp format you are getting from the server:

```js
const timestamp = '2019-02-01 14:28:16';
const [y, m, d, hh, mm, ss] = timestamp.match(/\d+/g);
const date = new Date(Date.UTC(y, m - 1, d, hh, mm, ss));
console.log(JSON.stringify(date));

// date as UTC string
console.log(date.toUTCString());

// date as local string
console.log(date.toString());
```